# Is there a best practice remediation for PhpStorm's warning that void function the_post_thumbnail is used?

Tags: plugins, functions, post-thumbnails

In a plugin I'm working on there is a line:

`echo the_post_thumbnail(array(155,55));`

It throws a inspection warning:

> 'void' function 'the_post_thumbnail' result used

Is there a best practice method of dealing with this or is the PhpStorm inspection overly aggressive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple, don't `echo` the result of that function, there is no result to echo.

```php
echo the_post_thumbnail(array(155,55));
```

Is equivalent to something like this:

```php
echo '';
the_post_thumbnail(array(155,55));
```

Functions that begin with `the_` in WP don't return things, they output things. Some of them let you pass a parameter that lets them return instead, but those are the exception, also don't do that.

The `echo` is both unnecessary, and incorrect PHP.

So, just use this:

```php
the_post_thumbnail([ 155, 55 ]);
```

Notice I also swapped the old style array syntax for modern array syntax, and spaced out the parameters.